# Intellij debugger hangs saying process <pid> is connecting

Tags: macos, debugging, intellij-idea

I had been successfully debugging a python script. At a certain point this problem started happening and even after restarting IJ it continues to occur. Screenshot shows the console .

I am running ij12 ultimate on osx 10.8.4

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the program itself was waiting for sys.stdin. Now, why the debugger did not even connect for a few times in a row that I ran it is not clear to me.